# What is this strange formation near Râmnicu Vâlcea?

Tags: geology, geomorphology, mountain-building

So I was browsing Google Earth the other day and I found this strange formation near Râmnicu Vâlcea, at about [45°07'N 24°16'E](https://www.google.ca/maps/place/R%C3%A2mnicu+V%C3%A2lcea,+Romania/@45.1032811,24.2630868,68696m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m2!3m1!1s)

[image: One view]
[image: Another view]

It's an almost circular region, about 40 km in diameter which to my eyes looks like a multi ringed impact crater, but then again it's near a mountain chain so it could be just some random feature created by the converging tectonic plates. But what could cause the hills to be arranged in this strange manner?

#### Elevation profiles

North-South:
[image: NS profile]

East-West
[image: EW profile]

Comment: Personally I'm not convinced there's anything there. It is only really evident in the bottom half of the circle. I'm inclined to think it's just a few roughly parallel river valleys.

Comment: This question deserves a great investigative answer.

Comment: @JanDoggen you're right the picture is skewed. I added another view from top. As well as elevation profiles also obtained from Google Earth.
I'm wouldn't be able to provide any more than this as I don't live in the area so I can't perform any readings myself.

Comment: It has been suggested that land morphology near Râmnicu Vâlcea may have been the result of a large meteor (bolide) strike.

Comment: @GaryKindel: do you have any more information on this?  Perhaps nothing has been peer reviewed, but who has made this suggestion/how popular it is/what evidence they have?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is streams fed by mountains that have been tectonically compressed and is undergoing some rotation. Near Italy are 3 tectonic boundary. Convergent, transform, and divergent. Due to the plate motion of the Eurasian plate, to the African plate, and the Arabian plate, it is causing compression and what I can describe as some rotation the land. It appears to be an involved relationship. I used Google Earth to create this map:

[image: Image of eastern Med and Caspian]

I hope I helped or gave you a direction to look. As you can see by the arrows, there are areas of convergence that are oblique and related in a way, that his geologic feature is not at all impossible.

#### Other sources

- [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=geology+of+the+trasnsylvanian+alsp&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1-ab)
- [Earthquakes in Italy](https://emmanolanlaquilaearthquakeitaly2009.weebly.com/cause.html)